# Subgroup examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to think of examples to these last two questions

For each part below, provide a group $G$ and a proper, non-trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$ according to the different criteria. Provide a different group $G$ in each case.

> $G$ is infinite and abelian and $H$ is infinite and not cyclic

The second example

> $G$ is infinite and non-abelian and $H$ is infinite and cyclic

As the question wants a different $G$ for each, I've already used $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition and $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (special linear group under multiplication)

For the last one I was thinking perhaps using $G = M_n(\mathbb{R})$ under multiplication but couldn't think of a suitable subgroup of the square matrices which is cyclic.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Try direct products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two hints: use $G = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ for the first question and $G = \mathbb{Z} \times Sym(3)$ for the second. If you know the infinite dihedral group that will also work for question two.

Answer (score 6):

- $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ which is not cyclic (in fact not finitely generated).
- The group of bijections $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ contains the element $x \mapsto x+1$. It generates an infinite cyclic subgroup, consisting of of translations.

Comment: Dear Martin, may I ask you to see my attempt here. Thank you for giving me the time. Thanks and +1.

Answer (score 3):

For 1,  take $G=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

For 2, pick $G_0$ any non-Abelian group. Then set $G=\mathbb{Z}\times G_0$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For part one, how about $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and then you can take $H=G$ (or if you want a proper subgroup, take $H=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

For part two, you could take $G=\operatorname{Mat}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ (under addition) and $H=\left\langle\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)\right\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

If $t(G)$ shows the subgroup of all torsion elements of $G$, so $t(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)=(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$. Both of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ are infinte and $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is not cyclic. This is a bit similar to what @Martin noted. From this point of view, we can see that $$(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)[p]=\mathbb Z_p, ~~ p~~\text{is prime}$$ so if we take $G=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\times S_3$, then $$H=\mathbb Z_n\times\{id\}$$ will be the abelian **finite** cyclic subgroup of non-abelian infinite $G$. **You didn't ask this latter example** and I hope you use it somewhere.

Comment: Nice and helpful addition! +1